# Why the Post appears which is already reviewed?

Tags: discussion, support, review

Whenever I go to review First Posts.

It shows the Posts that are already reviewed or edited by the Moderators or other 2K+ users?

Then why does it shows those Post that are already reviewed?

Any ideas?